# Getting cumulative count

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Column1 Column2

```
1        Sharp
2        Sharp  
3        Sharp 
4        Eye
5        Eye
```

I need output as

Total Name

```
3     Sharp
2     Eye
```

I am trying to get the output in mysql select query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless there's something I'm missing, use:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS numCount,
         t.column2             
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.column2
ORDER BY numCount DESC
```